# .htaccess - mod-rewrite and redirecting profile URLs with parameters to clean ones

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

I have links to user profiles like:

```
https://example.com/chat/index.php?action=user&member=547
https://example.com/chat/index.php?action=user&member=11540
```

etc.

My goal is to mod-rewrite such URLs so that they look nicer, ie. they should look like:

```
https://example.com/chat/member-547/
https://example.com/chat/member-11540/
```

etc.

And URLs without a trailing slash, ie.

```
https://example.com/chat/member-547
```

should be 301-forwarded to one with slash, ie.

```
https://example.com/chat/member-547/
```

So in .htaccess I tried this, but only the first line seems to work and it's not complete:

```
RewriteRule ^chat/member-([0-9]+)/$ ./index.php?action=user&member=$1
RewriteRule ^chat/member-([0-9]+)$ /member-$1/ [R=301,L]
```

**TO SUMMARIZE:**

1. When someone enters URL like:

   ```
   https://example.com/chat/index.php?action=user&member=547
   ```

   it should be 301-redirected to:

   ```
   https://example.com/chat/member-547/
   ```
2. When someone enters:

   ```
   https://example.com/chat/member-547
   ```

   it should also be 301-redirected to:

   ```
   https://example.com/chat/member-547/
   ```

I hope there's an efficient way to do it right.

Answer (score 2):

Starkeen's answer is correct, and will work. I'll just suggest an alternative, which acts on the raw request variable itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /chat/index\.php\?action=user&(member)=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^chat/index\.php$ /chat/%1-%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^chat/member-([0-9]+)$ /member-$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^chat/(member)-(\d+)/$ /chat/index.php?action=user&$1=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=([^&]+)&member=(.+)$
RewriteRule /chat/index\.php$ /chat/member-%2/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^chat/member-(.+)/?$ /chat/index.php?action=user&member=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you - I hope it's the most efficient/fastest way? (I'm not sure if this !200 status should be there and there's no 301-redirection status?)

Comment: @Tom !200  in the condition is an instruction to the rule not to run when status is 200. It avoids rewrite loop error.

Comment: I have added a 301 flag to the rule.